# GROUP_CONCAT using where in is not working as expected

Tags: mysql, sql

I got a table [country] as follow

```
 id  | country_name
-----+---------------
 1     India
 2     USA
 3     Nepal
 4     SriLanka
```

When I try querying as follows, it works as expected

```
select group_concat(country_name) 
from country 
where id in (1, 2)
```

I get the result as I want

```
 India,USA
```

But when I try the query using this way, I get a different result

```
select GROUP_CONCAT(country_name) 
from country
where id in (CONVERT(REPLACE(REPLACE('[1,2]','[',''),']', ''), CHARACTER));
```

The result I get is

```
India
```

Require help in this regard.

Comment: What is the goal of the second query?

Comment: i am using it to log inside a trigger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last i found the answer

```
select GROUP_CONCAT(country_name) from country where FIND_IN_SET(id,REPLACE(REPLACE('[1,2]','[',''),']',''));
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this !

```
select GROUP_CONCAT(country_name) from country
where id in (CONVERT(varchar,REPLACE(REPLACE('[1,2]','[',''),']','')));
```

Comment: getting syntax error on convert

Comment: if your id filed is integer then remove convert function.

Comment: even after removing convert the output is wrong.

Comment: select REPLACE(REPLACE('[1,2]','[',''),']','')) it result is 1,2 then your where condition like this id in (1,2)

Comment: it is working ?

Comment: nope it's not working

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you use the second query
but you may try using json

```sql
select GROUP_CONCAT(country_name) from country where JSON_SEARCH(CAST('["1","2"]' AS JSON), "one", id )
```

Using json_search mysql will look id in your json array.
The problem is, it works with ["1","2"] and not [1,2]